# Why sometimes apk is installed in /data/app folder?

Tags: android, filesystems

Some apk's is installed in /data/app folder and sometimes not. Is this because there is /system/app/ and also search path? I ask this because the /data partition is very expensive and I want to avoid badly written apk's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/data/app` is the default location for installed APKs. The only exceptions are system apps, which are in `/system/app/` and commercial apps from the Play store.

PS: Can anyone find anything on where these commercial apps are stored? Am I even right about that? Think I read it somewhere, but cannot find anything now...